# Find generic type over reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a small snipped of code, which checks, wehter an class exists or not.

At first i load all available types:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    try
    {
        types.AddRange(asm.GetTypes());
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
    {
        types.AddRange(e.Types.Where(t => t != null));
    }
}
```

Than i concat namespace and class name (which should be checked):

```
string fullName = ns.Trim() + "." + classToProof.Trim();
```

And in the and, i check wether the class exists:

```
int found = types.Where(innerItem => innerItem.FullName == fullName).ToList().Count;
```

But i have the problem, that if i check generic classes, for example `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`, `found` is always **0** (should be 1).

Does anyone has an idea, why this happens?

**Solution**:

```
List<string> types = new List<string>();

foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    try
    {
        types.AddRange(asm.GetTypes().Select(item => (!item.FullName.Contains("`") ? item.FullName : item.FullName.Substring(0, item.FullName.IndexOf("`")))));
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
    {
        types.AddRange(e.Types.Where(t => t != null).Select(item => (!item.FullName.Contains("`") ? item.FullName : item.FullName.Substring(0, item.FullName.IndexOf("`")))));
    }
}
```

I removed all ` from the full name, and fill a prepared list of strings.

Thank you

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft This is absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because generic uses ``  with a number that indicates the generic argument count like **List`1**. And your type name does not have it. To prevent this I would suggest checking the type directly instead of name:

```
 types.Where(t => t == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
```

Or you can use `Substring` and `IndexOf` to get the part before ``

```
int found = types
 .Where(t => t.IsGenericType
                ? t.FullName.Substring(0,t.FullName.IndexOf('`'))  == fullName 
                : t.FullName == fullName).ToList().Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but Matias is right, your solution is technically wrong.

The main problem is, that in a namespace types with the same name but with different type args can coexists at the same time. So this is valid:

```
SomeNameSpace
{
    public class MyType {}     // FullName: SomeNameSpace.MyType   
    public class MyType<T> {}  // FullName: SomeNameSpace.MyType`1
}
```

So, when you try to find System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary, you are actually trying to find a class with name "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary" but with 0 type arguments. There is no such type in System.Collections.Generic.

If you want to find System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary, that's OK, but the full name of that type is "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2", where the backtick followed by the number 2 means that you talk about a generic type with 2 type args.

Your solution may works, and may solves your concrete problem, but you have to understand that it is technically wrong, because if you removes the backtick-part of the generic typenames, then you actually merges all generic versions of a type into one name. So be aware, and consider using your original code (which is OK), and the correct name of the generic types.